# Tag synonyms for realtek

Tags: discussion

These days a lot of questions are asked about problems with Realtek rtl8188be, rtl8723be, rtl8188eu and many other cards. Solutions are same. But it is hard to find them. I can't find solutions unless I look into my answer history.

I think it makes sense to get these adapter names synonyms to `realtek` tag. Or create a `realtek-wireless` tag. But the second will take some work to retag. Most of "realtek" questions are regarding wireless either way.

Comment: I can only find two relevant tags - [tag:realtek] & [tag:rtl8192ce] - the latter refers to a driver for use on some cards. Not all realtek devices are wireless cards, I think there are quite alot of sound cards, sd card readers, wired internet etc.

Comment: What I suggest is to make all realtek card models synonyms to realtek, so if someone asks about a specific card, realtek tag would be applied. Or make a realtek-wireless tag.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your first point, it's not hard to find information about realtek wireless drivers. In fact, if you search for the tags `realtek` and `wireless` together, [quite a few](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/realtek+wireless) results come up in search.

For your second point, I don't think there needs to be a tag synonym. If anything, you should go ahead and create a new tag. There are already tags for for `intel-graphics`, `intel-wireless`, `amd-graphics`, and `amd-processor`, so there's precedent for what you're doing.

Go create a tag!

Comment: But still synonyms are needed. People ask abut these models. In most cases the do not tyoe "realtek". This way tag will appear automatically. The whole point is that I add these taggs every day.

Comment: @Pilot6 I believe Wilf has it down pat, and so does camconn.  We don't need one massive synonym that matches all the models.  We would have to do the same for Broadcom, and many others if we did this.  How many different model cards did you say there were again?  (basically, go research how many model cards exist for a given brand then count that, then realize how unfeasible your proposal is)